# How to add double slash for \r\n to \\r\\n in php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am creating a insertion query and retrieving the query by php and setup the data to input form using jQuery. but there is a new line issue which showing jQuery error and data not showing in input form. the sql insert query was :

> INSERT INTO challan
>   (to_messers,challan_date,address,transportation_type,trailer_no,driver_name,in_outstatus,vessel_name,rotation_no,voyage_no,yard_no,country_name,gate_no,remarks)
>   VALUES ("Marks
>   textile","2016-01-15","Welcome","CCTCL","DME-233000","Maksud","GateIn","KOTA
>   AKBAR","2015/2069","X","Yard-1","16","Gate-4","**test text\r\nweldone**")

After inserting when I retrieving the data and want to show it using jquery like below one

```
$('textarea[name=descript]').html("<?php echo $remarks; ?>");
```

It will be broken down to new line. check the image
[image]

Also mysql database input data is showing like below image
[image]

The text should be like this one.

```
"test text\r\nweldone"
```

I actually didn't understand quite cleary this part. if I change the input to double slash. 
    "test text\r\nweldone"

than it will ok and show the format correctly like "test text\r\nweldone"

Please help me on this matter how can my sql query have `\\r\\n` slash.

Comment: If you're referring to why you have to query it like `\\r\\n` then it's due to the fact that a single backslash is used for escaping things in PHP.

Comment: I m using raw mysql_query() function for this query. so how php is escaping it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you echo the string you want it to correctly preserve the lines using json_encode.  You can resolve the issue by changing this:

```
$('textarea[name=descript]').html("<?php echo $remarks; ?>");
```

To this:

```
$('textarea[name=descript]').html(<?php echo json_encode($remarks); ?>);
```

Read more on how to do multiline strings in JavaScript here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247331/747678

Read more on json_encode here: http://php.net/json_encode

> json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value
>
> **Usage**: *string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )*

Comment: Its working. but Now I get content with double quote. like - "test text weldone"  in the textarea input field

Comment: ah, that's right, we need to remove the double quotes for the html() call... look at my updated post.  Needs to be `html(<?php echo json_encode($remarks); ?>);` .. json_encode will add the double quotes and make it JavaScript safe.

Comment: Yahoo! its working well. Great help.You are a life saver man. but didn't understand why input is showing that way in phpmyadmin edit section. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used to escape a special character in javascript and mysql

In your javascript, the first backslash `\` allows the special character `\`, which is the second backslash to present in the string.

I think in mysql you can just try with `\\\`, which allows you to escape the `\\`